# Maintain paypal In-App purchase even after uninstall

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase

I have integrated in app purchases by paypal in my android app to unlock some features.
So a user who has unlocked these features can use them as long as he/she doesn't clear the app's data or uninstall the app.

In the event that this device/user does uninstall the app, and later reinstalls it, these previously purchased features will be locked.

So in short in asking.

1. Is there any way that the app can tie the transaction to the device such that after uninstall it queries from paypal over the internet to see if the device had the transaction done before so that it unlocks these features?
2. Are there any free back-end web servers i can use to store this information incase paypal doesn't?

NB: This is for appstores other than Google Playstore and Amazon

Comment: Not quite an answer for your question unfortunately, but the [Play Store guidelines](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) expressly forbid handling IAPs through any service but the Play Store's own. I would recommend not using Paypal for your In App Purchases. On the bright side, it should be relatively straightforward to restore a user's IAP when using the Play Store's IAP service.

Comment: This isn't for playstore. On playstore they have methods that do what i need, but this is for outside playstore like Opera, SlideMe etc but thanks

Answer (score 0):

from my point of view, you'd have an account for that user in your user database - holding his information, app / user account related infos and statistics, etc.
An in-app purchase would spawn an "Instant Payment Notification" message from PayPal to your server. The server receives this and unlocks the corresponding product for the purchasing user account. As this is permanently saved within your systems, there's no further need to query PayPal.

So rather than tying a purchase to one particular device - i'd have to check if we pass on any device identifiers, but i'd doubt it - you'd want to bind a purchase to a user account.

To directly address your questions:

============
1. Is there any way that the app can tie the transaction to the device such that after uninstall it queries from paypal over the internet to see if the device had the transaction done before so that it unlocks these features?

What keeps you from storing this information within your own servers? There are certainly ways you can query your own transaction history - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/ - but it's not part of the mobile SDKs, which you're probably planning to use.

============
2. Are there any free back-end web servers i can use to store this information in case paypal doesn't?

While I am not aware of any, they most certainly won't be free and I would not be able to make any preferential recommendation. If you don't find any ready-made platforms, it probably comes down to writing some code for this.

============

Comment: Thank you Martin. Well id would prefer tying the purchase to device and not to Paypal Account, because as we all know, Paypal accounts are easy to open, whats stopping me from opening an account, performing the purchase, abandon the account, disconnect the credit card associations to it and then make it's password public so say a blog that demonstrates how to use the features free by letting the user login via that account and unlock them since they were already purchased by that account.